# How to chain group_by, filter, distinct, count in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I am somewhat new to **data.table** & trying to replicate my **dplyr** code to **data.table** but unable to get the same results.

libs

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
```

**df**

(Have not used any NA in this dummy data but need to filter out NA's)

```
test_df <- data.frame(id = c(1234, 1234, 5678, 5678),
           date = c("2021-10-10","2021-10-10", "2021-8-10", "2021-8-15")) %>% 
  
  mutate(date = ymd(date))
```

**dplyr code:**

Find out ids that have more than one distinct date.

```
test_df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(!is.na(date)) %>% 
  distinct(date) %>% 
  count(id) %>% 
  filter(n > 1)
```

```
id      n

5678    2
```

**data.table** attempt:

```
test_dt <- setDT(test_df)

test_dt[!is.na(date), by = id][
    ,keyby = .(date)][
      ,.N, by = id][
        N > 1
        ]
```

Comment: Use `uniqueN`: `test_df[!is.na(date), if((n=uniqueN(date)) > 1) .(n), by=id]`

Comment: thanks @Henrik , this`uniqueN()` seems to be very useful & I think I will prefer this one. Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `distinct` in `dplyr` can be `unique` in `data.table` with `by` option

```
unique(setDT(test_df)[!is.na(date)], by = c("id", "date"))[, .N, by = id][N > 1]
     id N
1: 5678 2
```

---

Steps are as follows

1. Convert to data.table (`setDT`)
2. Remove the rows with `NA` from 'date' (`!is.na(date)`)
3. Get the `unique` rows `by` the 'id' and 'date' column
4. Do a group by 'id' to get the count (`.N`)
5. Finally, filter the rows where count is greater than 1